# [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'. QODBC3: Unable to execute statement"

Tags: sql, sql-server, qt

```
SELECT z.*,
   CONVERT(varchar(5),DATEADD(minute,DATEDIFF(minute,CONCAT(z.dateWork,' ',z.timeIn),CONCAT(z.dateWork,' ',z.timeOut)),0),114)AS totalWork
   ,(case when convert(time,z.timeIn) >= '07:10:00' then 'tolate' when convert(time,z.timeIn) < '07:10:00' then 'ontime' else 'pass' end) as statusIn
   ,(case when convert(time,z.timeOut)<= '16:00:00' then 'toearly' else 'pass' end) as statusOut
FROM(
    SELECT 
    [UserID] AS employeeNik
    ,MAX(CAST([TransactionTime] AS date))AS dateWork
    ,MIN(CAST([TransactionTime] AS time(0)))AS timeIn
    ,MAX(CAST([TransactionTime] AS time(0)))AS timeOut  
    FROM [NitgenAccessManager].[dbo].[NGAC_AUTHLOG]
WHERE CAST(TransactionTime AS DATE) = '2019-05-07'
GROUP BY [UserID]) as z
```

In SSMS this works successfully, but when I move to Qt Creator I have problem the following error

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'. QODBC3: Unable to execute statement

Comment: The entire SQL statement trimmed by Qt Creator? Another point: `MAX()AS dateWork`. Better to have AS surounded by spaces: `MAX() AS dateWork`